# How to set a css class to table header cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with thead cells.
I want to set a css Class to 'th' only where the value of this 'th' is "ID".

I tried this :

```
var T = [];
$('.tbl > thead > tr > th').each(function(){
    T.push($(this).text())
 })
for (var i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
    if (T[i] == "ID" ) {$('.tbl thead tr th').addClass('Myclass')};
}
```

But this Code set the class 'Myclass' to all headers of my table.

```
<thead> 
    <tr>  
        <th class="Myclass">ID</th> 
        <th class="Myclass">NOm</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

here is a fiddle --> **http://jsfiddle.net/1ck4joum/1/**

Thanks.

Comment: Its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/1ck4joum/2/

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165908/styling-a-css-item-depending-on-its-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
$('.tbl thead tr th:contains("ID")').addClass('Myclass')};
```